# Java 17 path exists() taking an extraordinarily long time when file exists

Tags: java, file, file-exists

I'm using Java 17 on Windows 10. I have a set of directories in this form:

```
data/dir-0
data/dir-1
data/dir-2
…
data/dir-999
```

I have a loop over the integers `0` to `999` with variable `i`. Within each loop, I just check to see if there is a `foo.bar` file inside the subdirectory:

```java
Path foobarFile = dataDir.resolve("dir-"+i);
if(Files.exists(fooBarFile)) {
  //do something; currently does nothing
}
```

If all the `data/dir-*` directories are empty, them boom, the entire loop ends in a flash (some small fraction of a second).

But if some of the `data/dir-*` directories contain a `foo.bar` file, the loop speeds through the empty directories until it actually finds a `foo.bar` file, and then suddenly each `exists(fooBarFile)` call takes almost half a second! (And each call takes the same amount of time, as if there was some clock counting.)

Then it gets even weirder: if I run the program again with no changes, it somehow "remembers where it left off", and will speed through all the directories until it gets to one it hasn't checked before. Then each `exists(fooBarFile)` call takes almost a second.

Note that this happens both within Eclipse and from the command line.

Why does `exists(fooBarFile)` take so long when the file actually exists? And how could it "remember" which ones it checked between running the application? I'm flummoxed.

*Update:* Apparently here is how Java 17 checks to see if a Windows path exists, inside `sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.checkReadAccess(WindowsPath file)`:

```java
try {
  Set<OpenOption> opts = Collections.emptySet();
  FileChannel fc = WindowsChannelFactory
      .newFileChannel(file.getPathForWin32Calls(),
          file.getPathForPermissionCheck(), opts, 0L);
  fc.close();
} catch (WindowsException exc) {
…
```

Yes, it appears that Java tells if a file exists by opening up a channel to the file!!

Tell me it isn't so. I just need to know if a file is there so I'll know whether it needs to be generated or not. I don't need to check for read access or anything. Isn't there a more efficient way? And besides, surely opening and closing a channel shouldn't take a whole second on a recent machine with an SSD, should it??

Comment: Uhm... I can't check now because not at home, but did you try with *foobarFile.toFile().exists();* Not sure if it uses the same code or not to test if the file exists.

For your question... perhaps the OS has a cache somewhere for the files, and it remembers if the file exists. I think that windows have a "findFile" service or something like that it uses to speed the search for files.

Comment: Luca, amazingly your hunch was right: `File.exists()` is much more efficient. It looks like the culprit is Windows Defender (see my answer), but still it's startling that Java is using that sort of check with `Files.exists(Path)` to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to Windows Defender. I went to **Windows Security Center > Virus & threat protection > Virus & threat protection settings** and added the `data` directory to the exclusions. Suddenly my program screamed through all the directories.

Apparently Java's approach for checking that a file exists (by opening the file) coupled with Windows Defender slows file existence checking to a halt!!

(I just verified this by removing the Windows Defender exclusion; the loop screeched to a halt when I ran it immediately after doing that.)

This is not a good thing. This is not a good thing at all. Neither Java nor Windows Defender seem to be doing the ideal thing here, either.

(I've also noticed that the first time I do a Maven build in a directory, it's horribly slow after a reboot until I've built the project once. I wonder if adding the project directory to the Windows Defender exclusion list would help …)

As Luca Scarcia suggested, `File.exist()` uses a different technique and amazingly seems to fly through all the directories, even without a Windows Defender exclusion.

Why, why, why is Java using this brute-force open-the-file to check for existence with Java NIO `Files.exists(Path)`? This is a problem.

Comment: I don't know the details, but file.exists() has its own problems and it's said to not be always reliable. Not sure why, because it always worked fine for me, but it seems it can have problems in a shared environment where other applications can access the same file.
Perhaps File.exists() is more reliable in those conditions, don't really know. Well, if you need that for work, expecially in a shared environment, perhaps you should try to look into it.

Comment: *"Why, why, why is Java using this brute-force open-the-file to check for existence with Java NIO Files.exists(Path)? This is a problem."* - Raise an issue ... with evidence.

Comment: I expect (I haven't checked!!) that the reason is that the old `File.exist` implementation is insufficient to deal with some edge cases, and that it gives incorrect answers.  So they did it properly ... because people complained about the incorrect answers.  Now a different set of people complain because the new implementation it is too slow.  You can't win with Windows.

Comment: Having said that ... `exist` checks (to avoid exceptions) are a bad idea anyway.  In the best case you ask the system the checks twice; once in `exists` and again in the `open`.  In the worst case there are race conditions ...

Comment: "Having said that ... `exist` checks (to avoid exceptions) are a bad idea anyway." I'm not doing `exists()` to avoid exceptions. As part of a data processing pipeline with hundreds of thousands of files, with a repeatable pipeline when there are errors, the pipeline simply needs to check whether the file needs to be downloaded or has already been downloaded. A later stage in the pipeline will worry about whether the file is readable or not. But we can't spend hours in the "acquire" stage of the pipeline just confirming that files have been downloaded.

Comment: One workaround will be for me to write my own logic to do a recursive traversal of the tree, put the paths in a map, and do my own "exists" logic by looking in the map. (But why should I have to?) Then I would have to worry about the huge map, maybe spilling some of it to disk to keep from running out of memory. Ugh.

Comment: Ah ... OK.  So your use-case for `exists` sounds to be a legitimate one.   But the flipside is that the reasons for the "slow" `Path.exists` will most likely be legitimate too.  Suggestion: try using the old `File.exist` API instead.

Comment: "Suggestion: try using the old `File.exist` API instead." I am a proud Java user and promoter. That suggestion does not make me proud to use Java, especially when I am constantly hounding my clients to upgrade from the old `File` API—not to mention in my [software development course](https://www.globalmentor.com/courses/softdev/io). This is disappointing to say the least.

Comment: Well ... yea.  I suggest you go have a beer with someone on the Java dev team ...